# Elementary solution to the ODE $u''+(x/x+h)u=0$

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the following ordinary differential equation
$$u''(x)+\frac{x}{x+h}u(x)=0,$$
where $h>0$ is a constant. I would like to know which method for solution is appropriate for the above equation and if the solution can be expressed by elementary functions? The best I could accomplish is a messy looking series representation of the solution. So I am looking for more clever ways to attack the equation.

Best wishes

Comment: This looks to be a very difficult equation to solve. I guess that special functions would be involved in the solution.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your comment helps a lot.

Comment: Meanwhile, I checked : guess what ! It is a **monster** ! Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claude Leibovici is right. The solution cannot be expressed with a finite number of elementary functions.

The functions involved are of the confluent hypergeometric kind (see below).

[image]